# Writing XDocument to XLS

Tags: xml, excel, linq

I am having my xml data in XDocument (LINQ). I want to write this data into excel data.
I am using console application.

I dont want to use excel com object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building Excel Files with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704030/building-excel-files-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can fairly easily create .xslx format documents without using com (or indeed without having excel anywhere near your machine).

There are links in this answer:

[Building Excel Files with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704030/building-excel-files-with-c/1704064#1704064)

And if you look in the latest [CTP for V2.0 of the open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en) you will find a very nice tool that will help reverse engineer the file formats into code as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

It may not suit your needs in this case but I have often found that writing to a .csv file (which will likely have an association with Excel if installed) makes for an easy to do alternative in many situations.